# How to read all the double numbers from a string using sscanf in c?

Tags: c, file, scanf, fopen

I have a text file which contains lines in different formats. I want to read all the numbers in this text file using c. And I want to read the numbers as a double precision number. The content of the text file is below:

```
 1,'            ',  13.8000,2,     0.000,     0.000,   1,   1,1.04500,  11.3183,   1
 2,'            ',  13.8000,2,     0.000,     0.000,   1,   1,0.98000,  19.9495,   1
 17,'1 ',1,   1,   1,  6000.000,   300.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,   1
 16,'16',  4000.000,   401.887,  9999.000, -9999.000,1.00000,  0,   200.000,   0.00000, 0.00550
```

I used fopen to read the file and used sscanf to scan the content in a single line. The code I have so far is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *fptr;
if ((fptr = fopen("rggs.raw","r")) == NULL){
   fprintf(mapFile,"Error! opening file");
}
int line=0;
char input[512];
int total_n = 0;
double ii;
int nn;
while( fgets( input, 512,fptr)){
    line++;
        total_n = 0;
        while (1 == sscanf(input + total_n, "%lf", &ii, &nn)){
            total_n += nn;
            printf(": %lf\n", ii);
        }
}
printf("\n\nEnd of Program\n");
fclose(fptr);
```

The output of the code is

```
: 1.000000
: 2.000000
: 17.000000
: 1.000000
: 0.000000
: 0.000000
: 0.000000
: 16.000000
: 0.000000
: 9.000000
: 0.000000
: 0.000000
: 550.000000


End of Program
```

and it doesn't contain all the numbers in my text file.

Comment: In the condition for the while loop, the call to `sscanf` has too many arguments for the specifiers. When you add `nn` later its just a garbage value.

Comment: Thanks user312102. My code works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code as below to output all the numbers in the line.

```
FILE *fptr;
if ((fptr = fopen("raw_data_IEEE_68.raw","r")) == NULL){
   fprintf(mapFile,"Error! opening file");
}
int line=0;
char input[512];
int total_n = 0;
double ii;
int nn;
while( fgets( input, 512,fptr)){
    line++;
        total_n = 0;
        while (1 == sscanf(input + total_n, "%lf%*[,' ]%n", &ii, &nn)){
            total_n += nn;
            printf(": %lf\n", ii);
        }
}
printf("\n\nEnd of Program\n");
fclose(fptr);
```